# How is attack strength calculated?

Tags: civilization-5

Sometimes I just can't figure out how the unit strength value is calculated in combat. For instance, yesterday I was sinking poor outdated barbarian ships with my sub, and when peeking at the combat preview I saw this:

[image: Submarine vs Caravel]

Why is the caravel's strength listed as `6` and not `15`? And why is the sub's strength listed as `130.8` and not `60 * (1 + 0.6 + 0.33) = 115.8`? Does anyone know the formula the game actually uses?

Comment: Sub vs. sailboat, how is that even fair?  Anyways, `60 * 1.33 * 1.60` is a bit closer, `128`, but still not quite there.  Maybe it's base damage is really `61.3` and it's rounding heavily to `60` :P

Comment: @Nick it may not be fair, but it *is* [historically accurate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinking_of_USS_Housatonic) :)

Comment: What Honor social policies did you have. Anything?

Comment: @Raven nothing... and even if I had anything, shouldn't it be listed in the bonus list?

Comment: @Oak - depends. For instance, you don't see the modifier you get based on your damage taken, even if, say, Bushido, is providing a large "effective" modifier. So, for clarity - what civ are you playing as, and is the unit damaged?

Comment: @Raven playing as Polynesia, and both units participating in the combat are undamaged, as you can see from the bars.

Comment: So, among other things, you're not taking into account your Targeting I, II, and III promotions (20% bonus each). What about wayfinding? Are you within range of a Maoi improvement? Unless that's what "Domain: 60% means"? If it does, color me stumped.

Comment: @Raven I don't understand, you can clearly see the targeting effects in the combat summary. It's not next to a Maoi, but when it is you would also see it listed as "+10%" in the summary. So the summary is great, I just don't get how the values are calculated.

Comment: You know what is really unfortunate? I think what we're seeing here is some bonuses being additive, and some bonuses being multiplicative. But like Nick mentioned in the first comment, it only gets up to 128, so clearly there's some confounding variable.

Answer (score 1):

130.8/60 = 218% =

- 100% (base)
- 33% bonus vs barbs
- 60% bonus vs domain  (that's targetting 3, right?)
- 25% unlisted bonus (it's unlisted because the screen is too short to list it)

A few possible sources for that 25%...

- Himeji Castle for 15% in friendly territory.
- Nationalism Social Policy for 25% in friendly territory.  <-- we have a winner.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, all combat modifiers are additive.

Ranged units use ranged strength to defend ranged attacks. Thus I can only assume that there's a hidden -15% modifier to the barbarian's 7, reducing it to 6 str.

It appears that the sub is being affected by an unlisted/hidden or off-the-screen 25% bonus that you aren't seeing:

60 * (1 + 0.6 + 0.33 + 0.25) = 130.8.